# Good resources for model binding in ASP.NET MVC3 with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I would like to know how exactly **model binding** works in ASP.NET MVC3. Since I am still waiting for my Professional ASP.NET MVC3 book and I cannot find anything by googling it, you are my last hope.

I know how to perform binding with simple objects but when it comes to ViewModels, especially with nested `List<T>`, I am unable to perform binding.

Thanks

Francesco

**UPDATE:**

For clarification, I mean Model binding from View to Action Methods, thanks

Comment: Why are you unable? You know you have to use @Model = etc etc? Well with a ViewModel it's just the same. But your ViewModel contains multiple data from various entities incomparison to a normal model which is usually a single entity (or collection of entities)

Comment: @Rhapsody: sorry, I meant binding from View to Action Method. Of course the other way around is quite straightforward. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not completely clear, so I'll address what I think you are asking for help on.

In cases where a View Model entity has a property of `List<T>` or some other enumerable, it is not automatically bound to the resulting model instance that is available in the action method marked as HttpPost.

You simply need to to find a place to persist the data, or, simply re-query for it in your Action method and update the posted instance.

The most reliable way I have found involves serializing the data to JSON and putting those values into hidden form fields, but when I do this, my view models no longer have the List property, but rather, the serialized properties.

This dilemma usually forces me to re-evaluate the need for the data to be available on form posts, and in most cases it is because I have tried to reuse a view model across views that have different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no changes in model binding have been made in mvc3, so I suppose chapter about model binding from [Pro ASP.NET MVC V2 Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430228865) is still valid.

I recommend to use javascript when you have to bind nested lists to action parameter.